# extract url part of the line

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I have html page with many lines and one of the line is:

```
var premium_download_link = 'http://www.someurl.com/';
```

how can I find that line inside html page and extract http://www.someurl.com from the line?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve or by what means. Be more specific, extract it where?

Comment: to a variable in the bash script.

Comment: It is javascript, the actual link might be different and it might require something constructed in the script or a cookie when that page is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n -e "s/.*var premium_download_link = '\([^']*\)';.*/\1/p"
```

The `-n` flag suppresses printing unless we explicitly print using `p`.  Thus only matched (then substituted) lines are printed.

**EDIT (based on OP comment):**

To get this in a shell variable you might want something like:

```
url=$(wget -qO - "http://originalurl.com/" | sed -n -e "s/.*var premium_download_link = '\([^']*\)';.*/\1/p")
```

This fetches the page and runs it through `sed`. The output should be the url, which gets stored in a variable named `url`.

Comment: i forgot to put ";" at the end. Can u tell me how to get without it?

Comment: @cikatomo I've updated to include accounting for the `;`. Basically, you just add that to the pattern, outside the group and it too goes away.

Comment: so this is basically substitution command, but instead of substituting you can keep part of the line.

Comment: it seems that is giving some extra space at the beginning

Comment: @cikatomo Wrapped it so that it should now discard those spaces.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "var premium_download_link = 'http://www.someurl.com/'" | awk '{print substr ($4,2,23)}'
```

Answer (score 2):

With awk :

```
awk -F "'" '{ for (f=1; f<=(NF-1)/2; f++) print $(f*2) }' $1
```

`-F "'"`  define the quote `'` as the separator for given input.

Comment: LOL! Some programmers answering questions on SO seem to be in a contest about producing the shortest piece of code which works on the given examples which are taken completely literally.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` you can extract specific field values by defining the field separator variable.

For instance, the following should work -

```
$ echo "var premium_download_link = 'http://www.someurl.com/';" | 
awk -F"'" '{ print $2 }' 
http://www.someurl.com/
```

However, your `html` file may have other content. So you can add a regex in front of the script to ensure that it runs only when the specific line is encountered.

For example -

```
awk -F"'" '/premium_download_link/{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: @cikatomo Not sure, but you can run both commands with `time` and see which one finishes off faster. They should be close as both parses thru each line.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -Po "(?<=premium_download_link = ')[^']+"
```